# How to start function after another is ends

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to start function StartGame() after my Animation ends. I have this function:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DominoAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 startPos = new Vector2(11f, 0f);
    public Vector2 endPos;
    private float step = 0.03f;
    private float progress;
    private bool isAnimationEnd = false;

    public delegate void Event();

    public event Event onAnimationEnd;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (progress >= 1f && !isAnimationEnd)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            isAnimationEnd = true;
            onAnimationEnd();
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, endPos, progress);
        progress += step;
    }

}
```

And when function in fixedUpdate finishes, I want to start another func in another class:

```
public class OnlineGame : MonoBehaviour
{    
    private void StartGame()
    {
        // Starting game
        if (DataController.MaxPlayerDomino[0] > DataController.MaxEnemyDomino[0])
        {
            DataController.move = true;
            domino[DataController.MaxPlayerDomino[1]].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
        else DataController.move = false;
        // Else not one have double
    }
}
```

I try to do this through an event, but I got an error through the fact that the reference to the DominoAnimation class is not working

Comment: Simply hook up to the `onAnimationEnd` event like `someDominoAnimation.onAnimationEnd += StartGame;` ?

Comment: I did so, but I had an error through the fact that there was no reference to this class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IEnumerator to to wait until isAnimationEnd is true like this :

```
private IEnumerator StartGame()
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => DominoAnimation.instance.isAnimationEnd);
    // Starting game
    if (DataController.MaxPlayerDomino[0] > DataController.MaxEnemyDomino[0])
    {
        DataController.move = true;
        domino[DataController.MaxPlayerDomino[1]].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
    else DataController.move = false;
    // Else not one have double
}
```

and call this function as a StartCoroutine(OnlineGame.instance.StartGame());

do not forgot to make instance of class and methods publics to you can call them on another class.

Comment: how to make an instance of a class correctly, because I don't know